# Insert query for mysql databse for datetime data type in cherrypy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, datetime, cherrypy

Here is my **insert query** which is working correctly,

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="", db="databseFile")
cur = db.cursor()
    print "source_id is: ",srcId[0]
    cur.execute('INSERT into config(col_1,col_2) values("%s","%s")'%(detail_1,detail_2))
    db.commit()
    cur.close()
```

And here is how to get datetime in python:

```
from datetime import datetime
currentTime=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I want to insert currentTime into my config Table.**What is the data type for datetime?** I searched on net, but i didn't find any solution. My question is, **How to write insert query to insert datetime in database(I am using cherrypy and mysql).**

I want something like this:

```
cur.execute('INSERT into config(col_1,col_2,col_3) values("%s","%s","WhatToWriteHere???")'%(detail_1,detail_2, currentTime))
```

Comment: Just use `now()` function built in mysql: `INSERT INTO table (datefield) VALUES (NOW());`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a built-in function, which exists in MySQL — `NOW()`. Here's how you may use it:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO config(col_1, col_2, col_3) values("%s", "%s", NOW())' % (detail_1, detail_2))
```

P.S. Normally you would use some ORM for interfacing with DB without raw SQL queries in more clean and safe way. Take a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: @ webKnjaZ ..i cant because my reputation is less than 15